# sklearn - why does gridsearch cv parameters result in a worse score than defaults?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I used `gridsearchcv` to hypertune the parameters for `KNearestNeighbors` on the training dataset, but surprisingly it returned worse results than the default parameters on the test set. Why would this happen? Any insight into appropriately used `gridsearchcv` would be appreciated, I need to do this on several algorithms to compare the default results to hypertuned results.

The `gridsearchcv` code:

```py
    # Parameters we want to try
    param_grid = {'n_neighbors': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7],
                  'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
                  'algorithm': ['auto', 'ball_tree', 'kd_tree', 'brute'],
                  'leaf_size': [20, 30, 40],
                  'p': [1, 2, 3],
                  'metric': ['minkowski', 'chebyshev', 'manhattan', 'euclidean']} 
    # Define the grid search we want to run. Run it with four cpus in parallel.
    gs_cv = GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(), param_grid, n_jobs=4)

    # Run the grid search (should only be on training data!)
    gs_cv.fit(train_X, train_y)

    # Print the best parameters
    print(gs_cv.best_params_)

    #{'algorithm': 'auto', 'leaf_size': 20, 'metric': 'minkowski', 'n_neighbors': 7, 'p': 1, 'weights': 'uniform'}
```

The results with these parameters:

```py
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=7,
                               weights='uniform',
                               algorithm='auto',
                               leaf_size=20,
                               p=1,
                               metric='minkowski')

    knn.fit(train_X, train_y)


    print("="*30)

    print('****Results****')
    train_predictions = knn.predict(test_X)
    acc = accuracy_score(test_y, train_predictions)
    print("Accuracy: {:.2%}".format(acc))

    train_predictions = knn.predict_proba(test_X)
    ll = log_loss(test_y, train_predictions, labels=np.unique(train_y))
    print("Log Loss: {:.4}".format(ll))

    log_entry = pd.DataFrame([[name, acc*100, ll]], columns=log_cols)
    log = log.append(log_entry)
    ==============================
    ****Results****
    Accuracy: 87.50%
    Log Loss: 0.3354
```

Using default KNN parameters:

```py
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier()

    knn.fit(train_X, train_y)


    print("="*30)

    print('****Results****')
    train_predictions = knn.predict(test_X)
    acc = accuracy_score(test_y, train_predictions)
    print("Accuracy: {:.2%}".format(acc))

    train_predictions = knn.predict_proba(test_X)
    ll = log_loss(test_y, train_predictions, labels=np.unique(train_y))
    print("Log Loss: {:.4}".format(ll))

    log_entry = pd.DataFrame([[name, acc*100, ll]], columns=log_cols)
    log = log.append(log_entry)
    ==============================
    ****Results****
    Accuracy: 91.67%
    Log Loss: 0.2398
```

Comment: You are optimizing a kNN model on a *training* set (`train_X`,  `train_y`),
which is subsequently, during grid search, divided into another training and
validation (test) sets and evaluated on them. That is, every kNN model
produced by a grid search is fitted on *subsets* of the training set.

Comment: Given I only have one dataset to work with, is the the appropriate way to go about it then? What would be the proper way to implement a gridsearch optimization with out additional data? Wouldn't the standard algorithm always produce a better result than the gridsearch because of this fact?